# javascript slow in IE but fast in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, firefox

It is very slow to access this page using IE, but much faster using Firefox. Especially when I increase the number of nodes of people. Any ideas what is wrong?

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example1.html

BTW: IE is even slow when accessing from local file system.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: have you ever wondered this: maybe it's just IE?

Comment: There is code in this page, http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example1.html

Comment: Any chance that you will be going through the 250+ questions that you've made and not accepted an answer for?

Comment: This just in: IE's JavaScript engine is slow.

Comment: Any ideas to improve performance in IE? Any plug-in to improve performance?

Comment: @George2 try [Google Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Internet Explorer's Javascript engine is slower than that from other web browsers, at least when using IE with versions lower than 9. So, if you're using IE 6, 7 or 8, now you know why.

Like raynjamin said, try testing IE using [Sunspider](http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9.1/sunspider-0.9.1/driver.html).

The latest stable Firefox (3.6) is fast, but for example, Google Chrome is even faster. A browser's Javascript speed depends on its underlying implementation.

**Update**: to give you an idea of how "fast" IE is compared to other browsers, I've done a benchmark on my own computer using Sunspider 0.9.1. Here are the results:

```
- Internet Explorer 8: 5039.8ms
- Firefox 3.6:          967.9ms (loaded with extensions)
- Chrome 9:             276.3ms
- Opera 10.6:           293.2ms
- Safari 5:             397.0ms
```

As you can see, IE 8 is about 5 times slower than Firefox 3.6 and almost 20 times slower than Chrome 9, at least when using Sunspider tests. That is a drastic difference and you can see that IE 8 isn't all that fast.

**Update 2**: There is one way to make IE faster. A plugin called [Chrome frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) exists. Using this plugin will make IE faster since it will use Chrome's engine. I haven't tried it personally, but I've heard good things about it.

Comment: Any ideas to improve performance in IE? Any plug-in to improve performance?

Comment: @George2: I've updated my answer about how to make IE faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome Frame is now retired and cannot be downloaded offically 
http://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html

Comment: A lot has changed since my answer. IE 11 is much different (faster and more standards compliant) than IE was 4 years ago and [Project Spartan](http://www.hotel-residence.hr/spa-cardio-fitness.html) should be even better.

Answer (score 9):

IE is slow. Fact.

Comment: Any ideas to improve performance in IE? Any plug-in to improve performance?

Comment: Sorry. There's little to do about it. Just write more efficient code.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript runs much slower in IE than in other modern browsers. You can test it for yourself using a javascript benchmark like [sunspider](http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html).

Comment: Any ideas to improve performance in IE? Any plug-in to improve performance?

Comment: Google Chrome Frame is an open source plug-in that seamlessly brings Google Chrome's open web technologies and speedy JavaScript engine to Internet Explorer. https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

Answer (score 0):

Guys Got the Culprit here... :) :)

After doing lot of RnD on Server side and Client side, I took a look at "Developer Tool" in IE. You can find something like "Document Mode: Quirks". If you check the Wiki page for this Quirks mode, You can find a definition as "In computing, quirks mode refers to a technique used by some web browsers for the sake of maintaining backward compatibility with web pages designed for older browsers, instead of strictly complying with W3C and IETF standards in standards mode."

So this all becuase of checking for compatibility for all components on page. And hence the performance issue. :)

And When I changed this mode to IE 8 Standard. Things started working really well.

IE and its issues ...!!!! :D

Comment: Now... how to get all the IE users in the world to do this in their browsers :-)