# Slow performance of JSP/JavaScript page over proxy server

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, proxy

I have the following architecture: a JSP page with JavaScript client code, the backend is a JAVA class that gets data from an Oracle database. The whole app runs on a WebLogic 10 server.

The timer function is in file RedbudTimer.js and the JSP page starts it like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/common/gp/js/RedbudTimer.js"></script>

function TimerCallback()
{
    window.location.reload();
}

displayTimer('<%= deadLine.toString() %>', true);
```

where deadLine is some number. The JavaScript file looks like this:

```
Date.ONE_SECOND = 1000;
Date.ONE_MINUTE = Date.ONE_SECOND * 60;
Date.ONE_HOUR = Date.ONE_MINUTE * 60;
Date.ONE_DAY = Date.ONE_HOUR * 24;
Date.ONE_WEEK = Date.ONE_DAY * 7;

function TimeSpan(d, toDeadline) {
    this.time = d.getTime ? d.getTime() : Date.parse(d);
    this.toDeadline = toDeadline;
}

TimeSpan.prototype.valueOf = function () {
var val = this.time - new Date().getTime();
if (!this.toDeadline) val *= -1;
return val;
}

TimeSpan.prototype.toString = function () {
    var t = Math.abs(this.valueOf());
    var d = Math.floor (t / Date.ONE_DAY);
    var h = Math.floor ((t % Date.ONE_DAY) / Date.ONE_HOUR);
    var m = Math.floor ((t % Date.ONE_HOUR) / Date.ONE_MINUTE);
    var s = Math.floor ((t % Date.ONE_MINUTE) / Date.ONE_SECOND);
    var showDays = false;
    var display = '';

    if (showDays) {
       display = (this.valueOf() < 0 ? '-' : '') + [d, (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h, (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m, (s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s].join(':');
    }
    else {
   display = (this.valueOf() < 0 ? '-' : '') + [(h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h, (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m, (s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s].join(':');
    }

    return display;
}


function displayTimer(time, toDeadline) {
    var ts = new TimeSpan(time, toDeadline);

    if (ts <= 0){
        setTimeout("TimerCallback()", 1000);
        clearInterval(intId);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('counter').innerText = ts.toString();
        var intId = setTimeout("displayTimer('" + time + "'," + toDeadline +")", 1000);
}
```

}

The way it works is, the timer counts from some number back to 0 and when it reaches 0 it calls TimerCallback in the JSP page. It works fine when it's run within the internal network of the server it is deployed on, but if it's accessed from outside through a proxy server it runs very, very slow (5 minutes to load the page).

Access to the application from the outside is implemented like this:

1. external access to app is done via Apache Webserver on border server
2. request from external user is accepted by apache via HTTPS
3. forwarder in Apache sends the request to inside network

I am baffled by this. Any ideas why it would be so slow?

Comment: What modules are loaded in your Apache server ?

Comment: this is what the configuration looks like:  Config file for Weblogic                   Forwarder/Proxy  
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>  
                WeblogicCluster [server name]:7001
                #WebLogicHost [server name]
                #WeblogicPort 7001
                WLSocketTimeoutSecs 10
                #WLProxySSL ON
</IfModule>
<Location / >  
                SetHandler weblogic-handler
                Debug OFF
                DebugConfigInfo ON
                WLTempDir d:\temp 
                WLLogFile d:\temp\wlproxy.log 
</Location>

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment. why does Stackoverflow make it so hard to edit a comment?!

Comment: does that answer your question?

Comment: Its hard to make out from that. There is an easier way out. execute this command _apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES_ . This is list down all the modules.

Comment: It can't recognize the command. It says: 'apachectl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable progrfam or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

@Santosh,

is this what you are looking for?

```
LoadModule access_module modules/mod_access.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_module modules/mod_auth.so
LoadModule auth_anon_module modules/mod_auth_anon.so
LoadModule auth_dbm_module modules/mod_auth_dbm.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule imap_module modules/mod_imap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule weblogic_module modules/mod_wl_20.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I am not sure if you need all those modules. I assume that these are modules loaded in  Apache Webserver on border server. I would suggest you to approach as bellow to isolate the problem.

1. Access a sample non-dynamic page (may be a simple static html page) and check if time taken to load that page is different when you access it directly and over the proxy (Apache Webserver on border server) ? This will make sure if there is any issue with your dynamic page per se.
2. Create and environment wherein you could simulate this situation. Host the apache web service which is acting as a proxy on the machine within the network, do the rest of the configurations so that you can access it in the same way you do with real proxy config. Test your application with this configuration.
3. If the problem lies with the Apache (i.e. its the culprit for slowness), the analyze all the modules it loads.
4. Check if you REALLY needs all those modules or you can remove some of them.

Comment: Another strange thing i noticed is that it works fine on Chrome, it's only slow when you run it in Internet Explorer.  The thing is that I don't have control over the server so I can't easily experiment and see what's causing the slow down. The server in question is at a client's site, I am a software developer for a company that did a custom app for them. I am maintaining it.

Comment: Difficult situation :-). Now next I could think of of analyzing the traffic between the server and the client browser. Use some tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). This tool will tell why it works fine on Chrome and takes time on IE.

Comment: I used two different tools to analyze the network performance of the same screen under IE and Chrome. To analyze IE I used Dynatrace Ajax Edition and for Chrome I used the built-in Web Developer Tools. The result is that the same files are getting loaded in both cases, they just take a LOT longer under Chrome. For example the file that took the longest in IE was a Javascript file called grid.js, which took 139 seconds while in Chrome it didn't even register, that's how fast it loaded. I am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Anybody else have any idea what might be causing this slowdown?

Comment: IE seems to have some problem with its javascript engine. (.js files are javascript files). Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398771/javascript-slow-in-ie-but-fast-in-firefox). Chrome use very fast [V8 Engine](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/intro.html) . Seems your problem may be IE specific (or some IE version you are using). Check you application in FireFox as well. Also check out [this comparison](http://robert.penz.name/122/javascript-engines-comparison/). IE seems to have problems in performance (_smaller the bars better the performance._).

Comment: I installed IE9 yesterday and it didn't make a difference, the screen was still very slow.