# Rewrite this jQuery find selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I am having performance issues in IE and using the browser profiler, I narrowed it down to this:

```
$tbody.find('> tr:not(.t-grouping-row,.t-detail-row)')
```

What does this exactly mean and any ideas on how to rewrite this so it performs better in IE (maybe pure Javascript if it makes sense)?

Comment: similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398771/javascript-slow-in-ie-but-fast-in-firefox

IE6-8 javascript engines are just really slow

Comment: pure JavaScript isn't going to give you much of an edge if you're selecting with a convoluted selector like this. If you're in control of the markup, you could give that element an ID and select by ID (either with plain JS or jQuery), which will have a performance benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, let's see together step by step what this means:

```
$tbody.find('> tr:not(.t-grouping-row,.t-detail-row)')
```

`$tbody` is a variable. It was probably defined a little before that. I guess by its name that it means "the tbody tag of a table".

`>` means "all the children".

`tr:not(.t-grouping-row,.t-detail-row)'` means "all the tr that DON'T have the classes "t-grouping-row" and "t-detail-row".

So your selector is "find all the TR in this tbody that don't have the classes "t-grouping-row" and "t-detail-row".

A better selector would be the following:

```
$('tr:not(.t-grouping-row, .t-detail-row)', $tbody)
```

But this would be just a little better, and still bad. You should review your HTML, see what you want and use a simpler selector such as `$('.class', $tbody)`.

Comment: That means something different than his current selector. For example your selector will traverse the entire tree of $tbody, while his only looks one level deep.

Comment: for your method to work it would be `$('> tr:not(.t-grouping-row, .t-detail-row)', $tbody)` but I'm not sure if that works.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is theoretical.

```
$tbody.children('tr').filter(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    return (!that.hasClass('t-grouping-row') && !that.hasClass('t-detail-row');
})
```

`.children` is more efficient than `.find` because it has less elements to look through, at this point the sizzle engine stops (sizzle looks like it might be your problem). The `:not` is replaced with `.filter` which would check attributes rather than selecting.